# escape backslash in encoded data

Tags: python

I have created a script which contains serial communication and DB connect for request.
retrieve data from com port is ok, exec procedure also works fine.
I have problem after data from DB are received. I need to send it to com port as an answer.

Answer from script is `"00000011D88A\x1b[2JSome text answer\x1b[1q\x1b[1q\x0d"`.
before it could be send to com port, the string has to be casted to bytearray.
So I use `.encode()`. But then the string changed to: `"00000011D88A\\x1b[2JSome text answer\\x1b[1q\\x1b[1q\\x0d"`.

How I have to cast the string to not change the meaning? I know that `"\"` is an escape character. But how to omit to use it, when the device need it?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. If I take your string `s` and run `b = s.encode(); s2 = b.decode();` then `s == s2`. Could you please clarify what you are seeing you think is wrong, perhaps with an example script we can use to replicate the issue?

Comment: If I use `encode()` on `"00000011D88A\x1b[2JSome text answer\x1b[1q\x1b[1q\x0d"` I get `b'00000011D88A\x1b[2JSome text answer\x1b[1q\x1b[1q\r'`. How come that you get a `str` instead of `bytes`?

Comment: I received from procedure a string s = "00000011D88A\x1b[2JSome text answer\x1b[1q\x1b[1q\x0d". After I use s2 = s.encode() that in s2 is now "00000011D88A\\x1b[2JSome text answer\\x1b[1q\\x1b[1q\\x0d"

Comment: `encode` returns a `bytes` object, not a `str`. Please post a [mcve].

Comment: I think re.escape() is comes handy in your case. The complete documentation is available in this link: https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.escape

Comment: Also I did not mentioned, that this happens only when I received an answer from DB. When I cast the string in python lets say manually, .encode() returns correct data.

Comment: maybe you shouldn't escape it. Python may display it as `\x1b` but it may tread it as single `byte` (with hex value `1B`). It has to display it as `\x1b` because this `byte` doesn't have printable `char`, Simply try to send it.

Comment: using `encode` it should display it with prefix `b` to show that it is `bytes`. If you get `\\` then there is something wrong with data in database. Maybe database converted it to `\\` and later `print()` display it as single `\`. Or maybe you should change code which put data in database.

Comment: if `print()` display `\x1b ` then you have already escaped `\\x1b` in string. If you would have `\x1b` then `print()` should change text color and skip `\x1b`. You could check what you get with `print(repr(...))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`\x1b[2J` is special code which terminal should use to change something in terminal (ie. change color, change cursor position, etc.) and `print()` shouldn't display it.

If you see `\x1b` then you have string with escaped `\\x1b` which is treads as three chars/bytes `\\` , `1`, `b` instead of one char/byte with hex code `1B`

You may also check what you get with `print(...)` and `print(repr(...))`

To convert string `\\x1b` to single char/byte you need `encode()`/`decode()` with special encoding `'unicode_escape'` (and/or `'raw_unicode_escape'`)

See Python documentation [Codecs - Text Encodings](https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html#text-encodings)

```
print('--- before ---')
text = "00000011D88A\\x1b[2JSome text answer\\x1b[1q\\x1b[1q\\x0d"
print('str  :', text)
print('repr :', repr(text))
print('bytes:', text.encode())

print('--- after ---')
text = text.encode().decode('unicode_escape')
print('str  :', text)
print('repr :', repr(text))
print('bytes:', text.encode())
```

Result:

```
--- before ---
str  : 00000011D88A\x1b[2JSome text answer\x1b[1q\x1b[1q\x0d
repr : '00000011D88A\\x1b[2JSome text answer\\x1b[1q\\x1b[1q\\x0d'
bytes: b'00000011D88A\\x1b[2JSome text answer\\x1b[1q\\x1b[1q\\x0d'
--- after ---
str  : 00000011D88ASome text answer
repr : '00000011D88A\x1b[2JSome text answer\x1b[1q\x1b[1q\r'
bytes: b'00000011D88A\x1b[2JSome text answer\x1b[1q\x1b[1q\r'
```

Comment: Helps a lot, now I have the same result like you wrote. And this raise another issue. "\r" on the end must be \x0d (CR). Otherwise my device is not able to recognize it. Device is Datalogic PM9500 hand scanner with display. \x1b = ESC[2J = Clear display. 
Do you know how to change "\r" to "\x0d" again?

Comment: as I know Python treads `\r` as `\x0d` - `hex(ord('\r'))` gives `0xd` but you can always try to use `text = text.replace("\r", "\x0d")`. But maybe it needs `\n` with has code `\x0a`. OR maybe it works different on different systems. I tested on Linux.